# How to prove squared distance is differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, normed-spaces, projection

Let $X ⊆ R$ be a closed, convex, non-empty set, and

$f(x) = ||x-P(x)||^2_2$

the “squared-
distance-from-X” function. Show that f is a differentiable function whose gradient is  $∇f(x) = 2(x-P(x))$

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE! You should begin with yours atempts, this may help us to give you hints or steps for your solution!

Comment: What could $P(x)$ possibly be?

Comment: ⊆  and P(x) ⊆X and x ⊆

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using non differentiable analysis (the references below are to
Clarke's "Optimization and Nonsmooth Analysis").

Let $C$ be the non empty convex compact set and write $f(x) = \min_{c \in C} \|x-c\|^2$.
It is straightforward to show that $f$ is Lipschitz with rank one and so has a
generalised gradient.

Note that $\min_{c \in C} \|x-c\|^2 = - \max_{c \in C} -\|x-c\|^2$, and we can write the
$\max$ as $\max_{c \in C} \phi(x,c)$, where
$\phi(x,c) = -\|x-c\|^2$. We see that $\phi$ is smooth and Lipschitz with rank one in $x$. Let $g(x) = \max_{c \in C} \phi(x,c)$ and 
$M(x) = \{c \in C | g(x) = \phi(x,c) \}$.

Note that $M(x)$ is a singleton and denote the element by $P(x)$.

Theorem 2.8.2 shows that $\partial g(x) = \{ {\partial \phi(x,c) \over \partial x} | c \in M(x) \} = \{ {\partial \phi(x,P(x)) \over \partial x} \}$. Proposition 2.2.4 shows that
$g$ is differentiable at $x$ and ${\partial g(x) \over \partial x} = {\partial \phi(x,P(x)) \over \partial x} = 2 (P(x)-x)^T$.

Hence $f$ is differentiable and ${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} = 2(x-P(x))^T$, from
which the gradient is see to be $2(x-P(x))$.

**Simpler solution**:

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x+h)-f(x) &=& \|x+h-P(x+h)\|^2 - \|x-P(x)\|^2 \\
&\le& \|x+h-P(x)\|^2 - \|x-P(x)\|^2 \\
&=& 2 (x-P(x))^T h + \|h\|^2
\end{eqnarray}
In the other direction
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)-f(x+h) &=& \|x+P(x)\|^2 - \|x+h-P(x+h)\|^2 \\
&\le& \|x-P(x+h)\|^2 - \|x+h-P(x+h)\|^2 \\
&=& -2 (x-P(x+h))^T h + \|h\|^2 \\
&=& -2 (x-P(x))^T h + 2(P(x+h)-P(x))^T h+\|h\|^2 \\
&\le& -2 (x-P(x))^T h + 3\|h\|^2
\end{eqnarray}
In particular, this shows that $f$ is differentiable with derivative
$2(x-P(x))^T$.

Comment: Does your simpler solution shows that the squared distance is always differentiable regardless of the closed set?

Comment: No, the solution depends on $M(x)$ being a singleton.

Comment: Which type of sets have $M(x)$ a singleton? Do such sets have a name or a different characterization? Do you know about that?

Comment: @copper.hat Great answer. You assume something quite critical before showing this statement, which is you assume that $C$ is compact and convex. At first glance I am not sure if you use boundedness in your \textbf{Simpler solution}. So my question is:                                         can this also be shown for a convex $C$, which is "only" closed and not necessarily bounded?

Comment: @Fredf Closed & convex is all that is needed. Locally, one can replace the set by a compact, convex set. The solution works in $\mathrm{R}^n$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for your quick reply, I am currently working with this formulation: $p_{C} : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow C \ \ \ p_{C}(z) = arg \underset{x \in C}{min} ||z-x||^2$, and $d^{2}_{C} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ \ \ d^{2}_{C}(z) = \underset{x \in C}{min} || z-x ||^2$. And then I need to use that $d^{2}_{C}(z)$ is a.e. differentiable for a closed possibly unbounded $C$, it seems to be the same question as the OP's, but I am having a bit difficulty, with the different notations. I assume  this is the same?

Comment: @Fredf Yes, it is the same. Note that $d_C^2$ is differentiable, but $p_C$ is not.

Comment: @copper.hat , so given  $P_{C}(z) = arg \underset{x \in C}{min} ||z-x||^{2}$ and $d^{2}_{C}(z) = \underset{x \in C}{min}||z-x||^2$ is the same as $d^{2}_{C}(z) = ||z-p_{C}(z)||^{2}$, since the projection is the minimizer so it removes the min in my formulation for $d^{2}_{C}(z)$?